# Reaproveitar o resultado de uma função no Where

Tags: mysql

Olá, estou trabalhando com MYSQL, gostaria de saber se consigo usar o resultado de uma função no where, chamando pelo alias.

hoje tenho que repetir o código, no caso essa função GEO

```
SELECT *,round(geo(-46.000000,-23.000000,latitude,longitude),3) AS distancia 
FROM view_empresas_pins 
where round(geo(-46.000000,-23.000000,latitude,longitude),3) <= 7
```

sendo que gostaria de fazer algo assim:

```
SELECT *,round(geo(-46.000000,-23.000000,latitude,longitude),3) AS distancia 
FROM view_empresas_pins where distancia <= 7
```

onde o resultado da função GEO é usado no where, sem que eu tenha que chamar novamente.

Comment: Você poderia colocar mais um SELECT em volta desse criando uma subquerie, é uma outra forma de se fazer, mas isso despenca o desempenho porque gera uma tabela temporária. Eu aconselho repetir a expressão.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar a função `HAVING` do `MySQL`, sendo assim você consegue trabalhar com o alias chamado na sua `query`, a consulta ficaria assim:

```
SELECT 
     *,
    round(geo(-46.000000,-23.000000,latitude,longitude),3) AS distancia 
FROM view_empresas_pins 
HAVING distancia <= 7
```

Comment: É, funciona nesse caso. Só vale tomar cuidado que o isso só funciona no MySQL. Having é pra usar com agrupamento, neste caso específico o mysql faz um group by implícito.

Comment: Excelente, deu certinho. muito obrigado.